# Microsoft Dynamics AX

Tags: axapta, microsoft-dynamics

I am trying to install dynamics 2009 ax.

I am getting error on create new sql server database error `setup could not connect server`.

please help to fix this error

Comment: Never. never write in all caps. NEVER!

Answer (score 0):

In order to install Ax, there must be previously a instance of SQL Server (I'd suggest 2008), Standard o upper version, properly installed and running. in same machine or in other machine but accesible via network.

Once reached this condition, Ax installation will create and manage a new database (or use an existing one, depending of your choosings) in that SQL Server instance.

And, please, edit your question and rewrite those CAPS, they're visually harmful!!